# How to perform Matrix operations in Netezza?

Tags: parallel-processing, netezza

I am new to netezza parallel programming. Can some one throw light about how to carry out, say a matrix addition in parallel using netezza ?

C(m,n) = A(m,n) + B(m,n)

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Netezza is a MPP appliance that can be accessed in a multitude of ways, but typically through the relational database with SQL. What language are you using to try to do this with?

Comment: This is usually something you do through Revolution R engine, i'd say. Additional cost for it though, since you need to license the engine from R.

Comment: @NWest Would it be possible to write in C++/Java to run in netezza environment?

Comment: @cairnz I don't think, a license for R is available to use. So I got to consider other options. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write the code in C++ you can just stuff it into a User Defined Function for Netezza.

See [here](http://guru-netezza.blogspot.no/2011/11/creating-netezza-user-defined-functions.html) for example udf in C++.

Your system should come with proper documentation for deeper reference of UDF and custom code for implementation.

Comment: Yes, I tried a similar example of finding smallest number in a list. I wonder how do we slice a matrix into parallel chunks for Netezza parallel processing? (say for matrix addition - doing addition in parallel column wise for A and B matrices to store in C matrix). Thanks for the UDF link though!!

Comment: You might have better luck hitting the [enzeecommunity](http://www.enzeecommunity.com/message/9616) for this, as they have people like Shaun Fox replying there. Atleast you should be given good advice there.

Comment: Sure I will give a try. Thanks much for the reference. Should I close this thread ??

Comment: You can mark the response as an answer. This does not prevent someone from coming in later on and giving a better reply though, you will be notified if/when that happens so you can review that as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is Netezza Matrix Engine which implements all kinds of matrix/linear algebra operations. It needs to be installed on your appliance. After that you can use SQL to call all NZM functions:

```
CALL NZM..INITIALIZE();
CALL NZM..CREATE_RANDOM_MATRIX('A', 10, 10);
CALL NZM..CREATE_RANDOM_MATRIX('B', 10, 10);
CALL NZM..ADD('A', 'B', 'C');
```

There are functions to convert tables to matrices and vice versa:

```
CALL NZM..CREATE_MATRIX_FROM_TABLE('TABLE_A', 'A', 10, 10);    
CALL NZM..CREATE_TABLE_FROM_MATRIX('C', 'TABLE_C');
```